# Vuex / Vue-Router - Passing auth:user id from vuex store to vue-router router-link params

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Is it possible to pass the current logged in user's id to the `params` of a router link?

This is my current code and I want to render information in a page based on the `params id`

**routes.js**

```
  { 
    path: '/objective/employee/:id', 
    name: 'employee-objective', 
    component: () => import('@/views/EmployeeObjective'),
    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
  },
```

**Component.vue**

```
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('authUserInformation')
    },

    computed: {
      loggedIn () {
        return this.$store.getters.loggedIn
      },
      authUser () {
        return this.$store.state.authUser
      }
    }
```

**router-link**

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'employee-objective', 
params: { 
  id: // this.$store.state.authUser <- does not work
      // authUser[0].id <- does not also work
}}">
Click Here
</router-link>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your router-link

Comment: `<router-link :to="{ name: 'employee-objective', params: { id: $store.state.authUser }}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in accessing store because by default, `this.$store` is injected to components so you can just use `$store` in templates, which then should be:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'employee-objective', params: { id: $store.state.authUser }}">
```

However, in accessing store state values, the recommended way is to use vuex's [mapState Helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

```
computed: {
  ...mapState([
    // map this.authUser to store.state.authUser 
    'authUser '
  ])
}
```

and so you can use this as so:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'employee-objective', params: { id: authUser }}">
```

Comment: I tried both of your recommendation and it both tells that the `$store` / `authUser` is undefined even though it is declared. Weird.

Comment: Nevermind I was able to make it work but it just returns an object.

Comment: @JimERussel what is the object returned ?

Comment: Okay that was stupid of me. I was using `{{ authUser[0].id }}` instead of just `{{ authUser.id }}`. Thank you very much! How about using the store data into a local component data? This doesn't work `data: () => ({ employees: $store.state.authUsers })` (different question from the topic, feel free to answer this)

Comment: Nice! By providing the store option to the root instance, the store will be injected into all child components of the root and will be available on them as `this.$store` so you can do this: `data: () => ({ employees: this.$store.state.authUsers })`

Comment: It produces an error Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined". I'm very sorry if I'm still consuming your time.

Comment: aahhhh! Sorry, didn't notice you were using an arrow function. Try `data() { return { employees: this.$store.state.authUsers } }`

Comment: You can learn more about normal function and arrow function [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions/). And don't worry. Just ast questions as you please :D

Comment: WOAH AMAZING! Is there a way to access $store with the arrow function? Or should I stick with the traditional way of `data() { return {}}` ?

Comment: Yes there is a way to access `$store` but you're going to have to do it like this `data: self => ({ employees: self.$store.state.authUsers })`. To whichever is better is your choice. I choose regular functions tho

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! (Sorry mods for the long conversation, I just really appreciate @karma-blackshaw

Comment: No problem @JimERussel! Enjoy coding :D